# How to prevent tableview refreshing cell data when scrolling down?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am fairly new to swift and wanting to create a tableview that records highlights from a sporting match (eg time, event, score). I have it working but whenever I scroll down past the maximum number of cells you can view at once the earlier cells refresh to the latest values for example the time will change to the current time. I'm hoping to find a way to prevent this.

This is my current code for the tableview. My tableview is denoted as Gamelog. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        Gamelog.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return NumberofScores
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = (self.Gamelog.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?)!
        cell.textLabel?.text = TimerLabel.text! + " " + "Score:" + " " + AScore.text! + "-" + BScore.text! + Gamelogtext
        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 144/255, blue: 81/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
       
                return cell
    }
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

//This is what I use when a button is pressed to input a cell.

Gamelogtext = " - " + TeamA.text! + " TRY " + A1.text!
                self.Gamelog.performBatchUpdates({
                        self.Gamelog.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: NumberofScores-1,
                                                                 section: 0)],
                                                  with: .automatic)
                    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is how UITableView works. It is done this way so that you don’t run in to memory issues with hundreds of cells. You should not be disabling this. Is there an issue with the way this is working?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I am using the UITableView to keep a running log of changes to score, substitutions and many more things. But when the user scrolls down when the number of cells exceed the display limit it refreshes the initial cells changing the time the event happened, the score. Would you suggest any other interface instead of a UITableView I thought it made the most sense but its proving more difficult than I first thought.

Answer (score 1):

You use table view to represent your data which is usually an array. So you should probably start there.

```
private var allScores: [Scores] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { allScores.count }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! ScoreTableViewCell
    cell.setupWithScore(allScores[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

The point mostly being that when you setup a cell with data you need to somehow use the index path that you received `allScores[indexPath.row]`. Even if you use a basic non-subclassed `UITableViewCell` and assigning to `textLabel`.

When you add data to table view you do need to update your array as well. So for instance

```
self.allScores.append(.init())
self.Gamelog.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: NumberofScores-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

this will trigger your `cellForRowAt` with the new index path that you inserted and you can use that index path to access correct data item.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am struggling to implement it but it does make sense. I was wondering if using a UITableView is the best approach. What I am looking for is a way to display data in rows. Then have the ability to save the data and retrieve it. To allow the user to save matches and look back. I had originally used 80 individual labels and it worked. It had all the features I wanted but I always knew it wasn't a very efficient method and I wanted the user to have an unlimited number of rows that appeared when needed. To summarise is there a simpler solution than using a UITableView?

Comment: @JackMartin I would really need more specific information on the project you are working on. But it does feel like table view is what you want. Probably you should have a navigation controller on top level, then a table view where each cell shows one match. Pressing a match opens a new screen where you can edit all the details. Also pressing to create a new item should navigate to new screen.

Comment: Yes, UITableView is definitely the correct way to display the information. I think you need to work on separating the actual data from the UITableView. The data shouldn't be stored inside the UITableView. The table view should just display the data. So store the data elsewhere in such a way that you can update the tableview with the updated data.